# ASP.NET MVC hidden field still getting name and passing to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this control that is hidden and the user need to check the input control for it to be `show`. I am getting the model fill with data and I wanted to see how I can only get data in the controller if it is selected ?

View

```
  <input type="checkbox" value="91" name="chkProduct">
  <label>Other</label>
  <input type="hidden">
  <input type="hidden" asp-for="Other">
  <div id="sourceSection_91" style="">
  <div class="row" id="ddRow_6" data-source="sourceSection_91">
  <div class="col-md-11 !important">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label source-label">Other</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="enteredOtherSource" name="enteredOtherSource[0].Other" type="text" value="">
  <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="enteredOtherSource[0].Other" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  <input value="91" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SourceId must be a number." data-val-required="The SourceId field is required." id="SourceId" name="enteredOtherSource[0].SourceId" type="hidden">
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1 deleteBtn">
 </div>
</div>
```

Model

```
public class OtherSourceModel
{
    public int SourceId { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
foreach (var ordermaterial in model.enteredOtherSource)
{
    ProjectMaterialUse _SelectedOtherProjectMaterial = new ProjectMaterialUse();

    _SelectedOtherProjectMaterial.Source = new Values();
    _SelectedOtherProjectMaterial.Source.Value = ordermaterial.SourceId;
    _SelectedOtherProjectMaterial.Other = ordermaterial.Other;
    _SelectedOtherProjectMaterial.IntendedUse = new Values();
    _SelectedOtherProjectMaterial.IntendedUse = model.selectedIntendedUseId;

    _permissionrequestWeb.SelectedProjectMaterial.Add(_SelectedOtherProjectMaterial);
}
```

Comment: I think it's based on how to send your data to your controller, if you used form submit, I'm afraid you can only add logic in your controller to validate if the checkbox is checked, if you write js to send the data, you can choose to don't send model data if the checkbox is not checked.

Comment: So I am using form submit do I need another option in the model ?

Comment: need to add `chkProduct` in your model, so that your controller can receive the value of the `chkProduct` to know if it is checked or not